# How to enrich a node value in OM property?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Is it possible to enrich a specific node value with enrich mediator?

My goal is to enrich this xpath:

```
$ctx:OriginalPayload//Partner[identifiers/businessId = $ctx:CorrelationId]/identifiers/otherId
```

I have tried these examples:

```
$ctx:OriginalPayload//Partner/identifiers/otherId
//Partner/identifiers/otherId
//Partner/identifiers/otherId/text()
//Partner/identifiers/otherId/node()
```

All gave me this error:

```
ERROR - EnrichMediator Invalid Target object to be enrich.
```

I'm using this syntax:

```
<enrich>
    <source xpath="//plat:CustomerAccountId"/>
    <target xpath="//Partner/identifiers/otherId"/>
</enrich>
```

Below is my payload which i'm trying to enrich:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns0="http://iszkody.lsn.io/service/internal/ClaimService">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns0:createClaimRequest>
         <claim>
            <InsClaimData VER="1">
               <PartnerList>
                  <Partner>
                     <RoleList>
                        <Role>UBEZP</Role>
                     </RoleList>
                     <BusinessPartner>
                        <partnerType>person</partnerType>
                        <personData>
                           <firstName>JANUSZ</firstName>
                           <lastName>KOWALSKI</lastName>
                           <PESEL>83248328432</PESEL>
                        </personData>
                        <identifiers>
                           <businessId>123</businessId>
                           <otherId></otherId>
                        </identifiers>
                     </BusinessPartner>
                  </Partner>
               </PartnerList>
            </InsClaimData>
         </claim>
      </ns0:createClaimRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

It doesn't look like a problem with payload or xpath but more like the mediator doesn't implement custom type.

Comment: Can you provide the XML payload on which you apply the enrich mediator?

Comment: I think you missed the intermediate tag BusinessPartner. Try once `//Partner/BusinessPartner/identifiers/otherId`

Comment: nothing has changed...

Comment: ok, i got it. not sure why but i had to change it to //*[local-name()='Partner']/*[local-name()='BusinessPartner']/*[local-name()='identifiers']/*[local-name()='otherId']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested the following in WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 and also 4.8.1 and in both version the following proxy did work (I enrichted the otherId with the businessId):

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Test_XPath" transports="http" xmlns:avintis="http://www.avintis.com">
    <target faultSequence="faultSequence">
        <inSequence>
            <sequence key="initSequence" />
            <log level="full"></log>
            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="$body//businessId" name="xpath" />
            </log>
            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="$body//Partner/BusinessPartner/identifiers/businessId" name="xpath" />
            </log>
            <enrich>
                <source xpath="//businessId" />
                <target xpath="//otherId" />
            </enrich>
            <log level="full" />
        </inSequence>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

As you commented that you now use the `*[local-name()='BusinessPartner']` syntax, this points out to be an issue with the **namespaces**. Try to use the correct namespace of the BusinessParter elements.

Comment: what do You mean correct namespace? does BusinessPartner element inherit the ns0 namespace from createClaimRequest ?

Comment: A XML element may have a namespace like `<ns0:createClaimRequest>` having the namespace prefix `ns0` which presents the namespace `http://iszkody.lsn.io/service/internal/ClaimService`. So the only thing you do when using *[local-name()=Something] is to avoid the namespace check. It may also work when you use the correct namespacePrefix:elementName. Don't forget to add the namespace in the proxy root element too.